# Generic Google App Scripts to import another spreadsheet rows based on the value of a column (condition)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a generic template which will import data from a master Spreadsheet, to a child spreadsheet based on a condition.

Example: Delete all rows in child spreadsheet, then, import all rows from master spreadsheet that contain "Yes" into the empty child spreadsheet.

The problem with this code, is that it only works within the same spreadsheet since it uses `copyTo`. In order for GAS to communicate with other spreadsheets, I need to remove `copyTo` and replace it with `getValues` and `setValues`. I cant seem to get this to work still.

Here is the current code I am using. How can I get this code (or similar code) to achieve what I am looking to accomplish?

```
function copyRows() {

  //Source Info.
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15a9...');
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  
  //Destination Info.
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1DtL...');
  var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destinationLastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
  
  //Condition to search for.
  for (var i = 2; i <= sourceLastRow; i++) {
    var cell = sourceSheet.getRange("T" + i);
    var val = cell.getValue();
    
    if (val == "Yes") {
      var srcRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":Z" + i);
      var destinationRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
      var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("A" + (destinationRow+1) + ":Z" + (destinationRow+1));
      
      srcRange.copyTo(destinationRange);
    }
  }
};
```

All of the previous questions in Stackoverflow seem to only be for importing data to a new tab within the same spreadsheet.

Comment: You could try to copy the whole sheet/tab to the other spreadsheet and then use copyto but using setValues and getValues is probably going to be a lot faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try this:

```
function copyRows() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  const ssh = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const svs = ssh.getRange(2, 1, ssh.getLastRow() - 1, ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[19] == 'Yes');
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  const dsh = dss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  dsh.getRange(2,1,dsh.getLastRow()-1,dsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  dsh.getRange(1, 1, svs.length, svs[0].length).setValues(svs);
}
```

- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you so much Cooper.  Worked like a charm. Never thought the filter function would work for this. I added `dsh.getRange("A2:AM").clearRange.clear();` so it will clear the child spreadsheet, instead of appending below previous imported data.

Comment: Hey Cooper, how can I change the filter function so it filters if the value is not "Yes"? I tried modifying the code like this, `filter(r => r[19] != 'Yes')` but it did not work.

Comment: I would have thought that it would have worked.  I noticed someone has been editing the code and they left the source and the destination sheet the same.  So if you took a copy of it to test with the change that may have been a part of it not working

Comment: I made an edit to fix `getastColumn()` to `getLastColumn()`. I just tried your updated code as of 10 min ago, and its now working using `filter(r => r[19] != 'Yes')`. Thanks! :)

Comment: I thought it should.  You really need to understand what you're doing if you are going to edit answers.

Comment: I agree, and was very careful before editing your answer. I only replaced `getastColumn()` with `getLastColumn()`. You were missing an "L" in your original code. So I updated your code to include the "L". But since it was less than 6 characters being changed, it would not let me. So I changed the //comments from lowercase to uppercase which allowed me to submit the edit request for you to approve (if you felt it was a good edit). I made no edits that broke your script. Thank you very much for your help! :)